# Getting all Abirik Chams

Tags: skies-of-arcadia-legends

I know there are three Abirik Chams in the game and how to get them, but I forgot to speak to the merchant in Nasrad while controlling Aika and now the city is destroyed and the merchant is gone.

Is there any other way to get that Abirik Cham, or did I just totally blow my chance of completely evolving Cupil?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The merchant goes back to the Weapon's Shop after you have defeated Blueheim in Yafutoma. You do not need to get The World is Round discovery before he reappears. You can get the Abirik Cham from him then and afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a [FAQ](http://faqs.ign.com/articles/529/529663p1.html) for this a long time ago, so I'm quite fuzzy on if you permanently missed it. Looking at it, I don't know either way.

If you did indeed miss it, I'll update the faq.

Comment: Thanks for the link! I've been frantically searching Nasrad and Maramba in case he took refuge somewhere after the attack, but no luck so far. I'll keep you updated.

Comment: FYI, you're missing a couple of Cupil upgrades in your FAQ. Cupil Lance + Abirik Cham gives Cupil Pan with At 145 and Hi 110. Feed him 12 chams and it becomes Cupil Weight with At 172, Hi 105 and Do 15.

Comment: @Kareen I'll update the FAQ to reflect that.